# Parameter in my C# controller read as null from the AJAX call

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to take input from Users through a checkbox and store it in a table in my SQL DB, I've created all the link properly and my post AJAX call works well because I was able to receive information in my DB. The problem is the parameter received in my controller is receiving a null value which is storing a null value in my table, I know that my checkbox is pulling the right information because im printing it before hand but I feel like my AJAX setup may not be stringifying it properly.

```js
$("#submitButton").click(function() {
  var results = {};
  $questions = $('#optionData');

  for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
    if ($questions.find('#option' + i).prop('checked')) {
      results['option' + i] = $questions.find('#option' + i).val();
    }
    newResult = JSON.stringify(results)
  };

  console.log(newResult);

  $.ajax({
    url: "/Home/SaveData",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: (newResult),
    success: function(data) {
      if (data == null) {
        alert("Something went wrong");
      }
    },
    failure: function(data) {
      alert(data.dataText);
    },
    error: function(data) {
      alert(data.dataText);
    }
  });
});
```

```csharp
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveData(string Options)
{
  dataInsertion dataInsertion = new dataInsertion
  {
    // questionID = object.QuestionId,
    options = Options, 
    // },
    // companyID = object.companyID
  };

  try
  {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      DB.dataInsertions.Add(dataInsertion);
      DB.SaveChanges();
      // RedirectToAction("Home");
    }
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("error" + e);
  }
  return Json(new { sucess = "true" });
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure your SaveData parameter should be the actual object type you are trying to send, and the data parameter in the ajax call is without the surrounding ()

Comment: Try changing it to `data: JSON.stringify( newResult )`.  If the data is not a string already, jQuery will turn it into a query strying, which your request is intending to send json, not a query string

Comment: Let the `for` loop complete rather than stringify every iteration. Then inspect request in dev tools network to see wht is ctully being sent